# What's the most efficient way to fetch the value from a serializeArray in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have the values of a form saved as a `serializeArray()` like so:

```
$('form').serializeArray();
```

This yields an array of objects, each with name-value pairs.  Like so:

```
0: Object
    name: "key1"
    value: "val1"
1: Object
    name: "key2"
    value: "val2"
2: Object
    name: "key3"
    value: "val3"
3: Object
    name: "key4[]"
    value: "array-val-1"
4: Object
    name: "key4[]"
    value: "array-val-2"
5: Object
    name: "key4[]"
    value: "array-val-3"
```

What is the most efficient way to get the value of a particular object with the name `key2`, assuming one doesn't know that `key2` is the second object?

How about the second item from the `key4[]` array (i.e. `key4[1]`)?  (Presumably from an name array input on the html form like `<input name="favoriteColors[]">`)

If this is easier to do instead from `serialize()`, I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the keys are unique, perhaps:

```
function byKey(arr, key) {
  return arr.filter(function (el) { return el.name === key });
}

byKey(arr, 'key2')[0].value // val2
```

Note the reason for `[0]` is that `filter` returns an array, so you need to grab the first element.

If the keynames aren't unique a larger array will be returned. It's up to you want you want to do with that, like: `byKey(arr, 'key2')[1].value` will return the second element.

You also could implement the above code into your function.

```
function getValByKey(arr, key) {
  var result = arr.filter(function (el) { return el.name === key });
  return result[0].value;
}

getValByKey(arr, 'key2') // val2
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/HBn54/)**

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately my serializeArray includes a few array names itself (eg. key4[], key4[], key4[]). How would you advise in this case? See revised question for details.

Comment: If they are the same name, yes - the function will simply return more than one element in the array.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was able to get this to work for at least the first item of an array like so: `getValByKey(myForm,'key4[]') // array-val-1`, but how would I return the second item from `key4[]`?

Comment: Use `byKey` but target the second element instead: `byKey(arr, 'key2')[1].value`.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an object that matches your keys/values, then access it like a dictionary :

```
myArray = $('form').serializeArray();
dict = {};

$(myArray).each(function(i, field){
 dict[field.name] = field.value;
 });

 console.log(dict["key2"])
```

Comment: Thanks. Would this also work with arrays like `key4[]`,`key4[]`,`key4[]`? (See updated question details)

Comment: Yes, I found the same. Any advice how to handle arrays?

Comment: Are they arrays or just array names? I don't actually know what you're trying to do.

Comment: The form is a mix of <input name="key"> and <input name="arr[]">. I need an efficient way of fetching the values from both simple name/value pairs and more complex name/arrays.  I want to fetch the values from both key2 and key4[2] (to use the example object in the question above) as easily and efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following :

```
$.each(arr, function(i, obj) {
    if(obj.name === "key2") console.log(obj.value);
});
```

Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/tcJuG/1/

Comment: Yes, but doesn't this require looping through each item? Isn't there a more efficient way?